# How can I download torrents in Ubuntu and what are the risks?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

I have tried out downloading torrents on Windows. However, now I want to know how to do so on Ubuntu.I need an explanation and some instructions  for it. I would also like to know the risks in it. Can somebody experienced in this please help?

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu comes with a built in BitTorrent client; I am unsure how to use it but imagine torrent links will open automatically. The [Ubuntu website has more information on it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitTorrent).

You're asking about the risks - torrents themselves are as safe as any other download, that is it depends on the source and what you're looking at downloading. If you're downloading from a legitimate source you shouldn't have any problems. See if the provider offers a [hash of the file to verify it](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) before running any executable content. If there are viruses they're likely to target Windows, but don't rest on that fact.

If you happen to be downloading content from an illegitimate source (i.e. usually if it's violating copyright) you have more risks, both an increased chance of downloading malicious data, and of legal ramifications. Generally if you have to ask about the safety and feel that your source is not legitimate or is known to be breaking the law you're best steering clear.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Ubuntu has an in-built torrent client named **Transmission**, an easy BitTorrent client from the project Transmission. All you have to do is just download the file & open it with the client. This may not be like how a torrent client looks on windows but does exactly the same functionality where a P2P client intend to do.

[image]

As in [**M1ke**](https://askubuntu.com/users/119948/m1ke)'s answer, Ubuntu itself has a separate wiki explaining about [**BitTorrent**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BitTorrent). Torrent in general is a P2P (peer-to-peer) service. Therefore, you may have pros and cons while downloading. I may not say its purely secure but it all depends with the users use; while checking for a legitimate source & reviewing a torrent file before preparing a download. You may also consider below points in general to make sure that its a good torrent which you're planning to download;

- Firstly, you need a torrent website which offers torrent, locate it & select the torrent which you prefer downloading.
- Review any information given to you, such as the date uploaded, the file size.. etc (This may help you to determine a good torrent file)
- Review any ratings or comments available to you (It is always recommended to refer latest comments by reviewing)
- Check for other sites linking to the torrent. (The more sites, the more chance the torrent is real).
- Compare File Sizes (Is the file only 5 MB, when all the others are 5
  GB? Does the file size seem too small? If so, it might be fake).

Hope this helps & clears your question

**Source helped to grab some points:** [How to Determine if a Torrent Is Real or Fake](http://www.wikihow.com/Determine-if-a-Torrent-Is-Real-or-Fake)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in program; When you download a Torrent it automatically opens with this one or download the other programs like: Vuze, which I have been using myself for some years!

I don't get the part of your question about the risk but in Torrent everything depends on you! You can download something which is Legal or is Illegal; You can download a Virus or a Song or a Movie... If I get wrong please explain more your question.

Answer (score 0):

if you used to uTorrent only what I can recommend to you to use qBittorent it's identical copy of uT almost 90% alike or some and also Ktorrent KDE looks good, fast and stable. All of them you can find at Ubuntu Software Center, if you wish mods go to launchpad or webupd8 etc...